# check data type of rows in a big pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file of more than 100gb and more than 100 columns (with different types of data). I need to know if each column contains the expected data type.

How can I check for each row of the chunk if the data type is the expected one and return a True, otherwise False? (note that since the file is big I open it in parts and all as str):

```
for df_chunk in pd.read_csv(path, chunksize=n, dtype=str):
    check(chunk)
```

For example, given the df chunk and the function check:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 'blue' | 'dog' |
| 'red' | 'cat' |
| 'black' | 1.0 |

```
check(df_chunk, {A: str, B: str))
```

Return

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| True | True |
| True | True |
| True | False |

Answer (score 3):

Try with `type` over `applymap`

```
df.applymap(lambda x : type(x).__name__).eq({'A': 'str', 'B': 'str'})
      A      B
0  True   True
1  True   True
2  True  False
```

Comment: TIL about `applymap`. You saved me from posting some shady implementation using apply and a `for` loop over the columns.